# Conditional Formatting using another cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet and want to conditional format Column G based on if Column D contains the word "Sale".

I have tried the following:
Cell Value = "Sale"

I have also tried the formula:
=D2="Sale"

Any assistance would greatly be appreciated.  I am using Excel 2013

Comment: In what cell are you setting the conditional format? G2?

Comment: When I click on G2 before selecting column G and then selecting Conditional formatting, when I use the formula above, a random cell in Column G formats (red), but that cell isn't "Sale" in Colum D

Comment: Column D has 4 options Sale, Rental, Foreclosure, Other.  Column G has the completion date.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your formula row reference aligns with your range the rule applies to:

If the rule applies to the entire column G, use

```
=$D1 = "Sale"
```

[image]

If the rule applies to a range starting with `G2` for example, use

```
=$D2 = "Sale"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, put this together just to show something:

[image]